# How do I translate "附件是我做的方案针对目前我们存在的问题"?

Tags: translation

How can I translate correctly this sentence?:

> 附件是我做的方案针对目前我们存在的问题

What do 方案 and 针对 mean in this context?

Comment: Attached is the plan (方案) I've made regarding (针对) the problems we are currently facing.

Comment: This is a Q and A site, not a translation service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowadays, people more frequently write(input) Chinese on mobile with IM tools. People usually write very short sentences or phrases, and then send it out immediately, then send additional words if the previous ones are wrong or confusing. When people get used to the way they input characters, it will also influent the way they speak Chinese. You can even see many people omit the punctuations from their sentences in Chinese forums.

Regarding your question, in fact, in my opinion, it just needs a comma:

> 附件是我做的方案, 针对目前我们存在的问题

Comment: Most of the time we use WeChat to communicate. So I think you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can translate like this:

> I made a plan that aiming at the problems we have. And i've already
>   put it in   the attachment.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I have never thought it would like so complicated to translate!

Answer (score 0):

支持倪阔乐同学的翻译。但我想指出的是，“附件是我做的方案针对目前我们存在的问题”是一个病句，甚至可以说这不是一个句子。正确的应为“附件是我做的针对目前我们存在问题的方案”。

I agree with 倪阔乐's translation:

> Attached is the plan (方案) I've made regarding (针对) the problems we are currently facing.

However, the original sentence is just weird. I would say this instead: 附件是我做的针对目前我们存在问题的方案.

Comment: 病句。真是个病句！同意。有的时候我浪费半天时间翻译一句。

Comment: I just added a translation of your answer to English. I hope I understood it correctly.

Comment: I would say “...的方案在附件里。”. The inversion "Attached is ..." is not conventional in Chinese and sounds translated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use "proposal" for "方案" and "focus" for "针对" in this context. Here is my take:

Attached is my proposal focusing on the issues that we are currently facing.